# Use script to hide an entire div based upon CSS condition?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am currently using CSS to hide a class if the image "src" is using a blank avatar image:

```
<style>
.s-lib-featured-profile-image [src="//libapps.s3.amazonaws.com/apps/common/images/profile.jpg"] {
    display:none;
}
</style>
```

However, I also need to create a condition (jQuery?, javascript?) that will hide the entire div (class="s-lib-featured-profile-container") when the above is true.

```
 <div class="s-lib-featured-profile-container">
        <a href="/prf.php?account_id=127256">
            <div class="s-lib-featured-profile-image">
                <img src="https://libapps.s3.amazonaws.com/apps/common/images/profile.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="s-lib-profile-div s-lib-featured-profile-name"></div> 
        </a>
    </div>
```

I am currently implementing the below script without success.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
 if( $('.s-lib-featured-profile-image').text()=='' ) {
$('.s-lib-featured-profile-container').hide();
}
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Related read: [Parent Selectors in CSS](https://css-tricks.com/parent-selectors-in-css/)

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you make the same query than your CSS?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 if( $('.s-lib-featured-profile-image img[src="https://libapps.s3.amazonaws.com/apps/common/images/profile.jpg"]').length ) {
    console.log('hiding...');
    $('.s-lib-featured-profile-container').hide();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="s-lib-featured-profile-container">
    <a href="/prf.php?account_id=127256">
        <div class="s-lib-featured-profile-image">
            <img src="https://libapps.s3.amazonaws.com/apps/common/images/profile.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="s-lib-profile-div s-lib-featured-profile-name"></div> 
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @sjahan. Thanks for this answer! It seems the most logical and eloquent of the responses to me, however, I am still struggling with getting it to work on my page.

If I am implementing the below, is there anything else I am missing? (jquery calls are built into the system I am using - Springshare).

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
 if( $('.s-lib-featured-profile-image img[src="https://libapps.s3.amazonaws.com/apps/common/images/profile.jpg"]').length ) {
    console.log('hiding...');
    $('.s-lib-featured-profile-container').hide();
  }
});
</script>

Answer (score 0):

Since you're already using jQuery, a quick solution would be to use `.attr()` ([docs](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)). It might look something like this:

```
if ($('.s-lib-featured-profile-image img').attr('src') === "//libapps.s3.amazonaws.com/apps/common/images/profile.jpg") {
  //your custom logic here
}
```

If you need to hide the entire `div`, try using something like `.addClass()`([docs](https://api.jquery.com/addClass/)) to add a class with the CSS property `display: none`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple snippet to show how you could proceed: select the child given a certain condition, then hide its parent:

```js
$('.hide-my-parent').each(function() {
  $(this).parent('.parent-class').hide();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="parent-class">
  hide me!
  <span class="hide-my-parent">
    hide my parent!
  </span>
</div>

<div class="parent-class">
  don't hide me!
  <span>
    don't hide my parent!
  </span>
</div>
```

And of course the complete, less readable code you could use:

```js
const defaultUrl = 'https://libapps.s3.amazonaws.com/apps/common/images/profile.jpg';

$(`.s-lib-featured-profile-image [src="${defaultUrl}"]`)
  .parent('div')
  .parent('a')
  .parent('.s-lib-featured-profile-container')
  .hide()
```

```css
/* just a helper to show that the div has been hidden */
.s-lib-featured-profile-container {
  border: solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- will be hidden -->
<div class="s-lib-featured-profile-container">
  <a href="/prf.php?account_id=127256">
    <div class="s-lib-featured-profile-image">
      <img src="https://libapps.s3.amazonaws.com/apps/common/images/profile.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="s-lib-profile-div s-lib-featured-profile-name"></div>
  </a>
</div>

<!-- will not be hidden -->
<div class="s-lib-featured-profile-container">
  <a href="/prf.php?account_id=127256">
    <div class="s-lib-featured-profile-image">
      <img src="http://picsum.photos/100/100" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="s-lib-profile-div s-lib-featured-profile-name"></div>
  </a>
</div>
```